would rather in the past
We have two different subjects. I want to refer to the past using "would rather". So, I have to use past perfect

I would rather you had done it when I arrived

It means that I wanted them to do something before I  arrived. How to say after "I would rather you did it when I arrived"?

I would rather you had done it before I arrived

This is very similar to a question by user Gregor: Does "by the time" mandate perfect constructions? and by user Adam: How to use "would rather"

Tell the truth, you (user203412), Gregor and Adam are the same guy. There's no rule forbidding creating  multiple accounts, but if you created a new one to circumvent a question ban, which is what I think has happened, you risk a suspension.

@Mari-LouA I don't understnad what you mean.  I have only one account here.

Well you ask the same type of questions as they do, you ask about the same verbs, and you don't show any research either.  Having multiple accounts is allowed, but I think Gregor and Adam were question banned by the system for low quality content.  If I were you, I would try to make your questions more useful, and include the research in your questions to show effort.

will try to do my best, thanks

Your sentence “I would rather you did it when I arrived" is ambiguous. It could be a (poor) expression of I would rather you had finished achieving it before I arrive. But it would be less of a stretch to interpret it as meaning I would rather you waited to begin doing it until after I have arrived.

How to get the intended meaning., then? "I would rather you had done it after I arrived"?

@Adam, do you mean that your preferred state of affairs is the one in which they had completed doing it before your arrival? And is this preference applying to a situation that has already happened (so you are expressing a preference for a counterfacual (hypothetical world different from the world that actually is)), or is this preference applying to events that are yet to come?

"I would rather you did it when I arrived" means I preferred you to do that thing when I arrived.
